# Powershell runspace: write-output calls made form inside a cmdlet that was called from scriptblock doesn't show as output

Tags: powershell, runspace

My write-output calls that are directly in the scriptblock show up in the runspace outputs.   But cmdlets I call from that scriptblock also make write-output calls , but they do not end up in the runspace output.

To get the output I call PowerShell.EndInvoke(Job).

Below is some sample code that the same code just run from powershell
Some sample code

**Non runspace code**

```
Function Do-Output{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [int]$n)
    Process{ 
    write-output "Output from inside Do-Output($($n))"
    }
}
write-output "Output from before Do-Output(1) call"
Do-Output -n 1
write-output "Output from before Do-Output(2) call"
Do-Output -n 2
write-output "Output from before Do-Output(3) call"
Do-Output -n 3
write-output "Done"
```

**non runspace output**

```
Output from before Do-Output(1) call
Output from inside Do-Output(1)
Output from before Do-Output(2) call
Output from inside Do-Output(2)
Output from before Do-Output(3) call
Output from inside Do-Output(3)
Done
```

**Code in a script block run from runspace**

```
Function Do-Output{
 [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [int]$n)
    Process{ 
    write-output "Output from inside Do-Output($($n))"
    }
}


$Scriptblock = {

write-output "Output from before Do-Output(1) call"
Do-Output -n 1
write-output "Output from before Do-Output(2) call"
Do-Output -n 2
write-output "Output from before Do-Output(3) call"
Do-Output -n 3
write-output "Done"
}
```

**Script block run from runspace output**

None of the write-output calls from inside the Do-Output cmdlet show in the output.

```
Output from before Do-Output(1) call
Output from before Do-Output(2) call
Output from before Do-Output(3) call
Done
```

I know the cmdlet is being called as if I throw an exception in it, that exception show up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I collect the return value data when using a runspace pool and begininvoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67338622/how-can-i-collect-the-return-value-data-when-using-a-runspace-pool-and-begininvo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the function in the ScriptBlock.

Comment: Its in a module  that I import in the ScriptBlock   I know the the function is being called.  As if I threw a message in it , It does show up as output.

Comment: Is the module installed locally on the target computer? Your question did not say the function was in a module. It was declared above the ScriptBlock. Also can you share the exception? Also, please share the exact code you're using... It's useless if you don't.

Comment: More weird behavior.    If that function returns a value and the caller doesn't assign that to a variable , all the write-outputs show in the output.   If the caller does assign the value to a variable , the  write-outputs in the cmdlet do not show in the output.    If I move that functions out of my bigger module ( 6000+ lines of code )  and it to its own module ,  all the write-outputs in the cmdlet work as expected in all the  scenarios.   But the goal is to get the bigger module to work in RunSpace.  Everything is running on the local system.

Comment: To note is that I am currently only using 1 function of the bigger module.

Comment: When I put the 1 function it its own module and that function returns a value and the caller assign it to a value, it too shows non of the cmdlets inner write-outputs.  If I remove that variable assignment  , all the write-outputs show again.   I stated incorrectly above that it works in all scenarios.  So I am note sure where to go from here .    I am using PSVersion                5.1.19041.906

Comment: I guess the behavior of write-output not outputting anything from a function if that function returns something , but return it part of the return payload.  Or if that function has no return , it also doesn't  output anything.    I used to use write-host as this does what I want always output , never make it part of the return payload.  But write-host doesn't output from runspace.  So I guess I need to re-evaluate how to output from my module so it works in both runspace and not.

Comment: Either you install the module on the target machine and import the module via the ScriptBlock on the remote computer or this is not going to work. As far as I'm concerned the initial issue is resolved.

Comment: If you have any additional issue obtaining the output from a runspace, this article is is good for beginners https://markw.dev/runspaces-explained/

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to create a ScriptBlock wrapper.  This script block wrapper will start a transcript before starting the real script block ( I have no control of that one ) .   then start the real script block with Invoke-Command in the wrapper script block.

This has several benefits.
I then keep using write-host in my module.
It also captures verbose output.